# Soql retrieving records through a lookup relationship

Tags: soql

I have seen quite a few posts on this here at Stackexchange, followed them as mentioned, for some reason it is not working for me.
I am trying to retrieve records from the custom Object[Segment] which has a lookup relationship with the Account Standard object.

Here how the field is setup in the Account object -
[image]

Here how the Segment custom Object is setup -
[image]

I still have no idea why the below soql statements dont work.

```
select Id,Name,Segments__r.Id from Account
select Id,Name,(select Id from Segments__r) from Account
```

For both the above queries this is the error message I get -

**Didn't understand relationship 'Segments__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work:

```
select Id,Name,Segments__r.Id from Account
```

because the relationship name is incorrect. As shown in your screenshot, the relationship field API name is `Segment_ID__c`.

Note also that you shouldn't traverse a relationship just to get the Id. The relationship field itself stores the id, `Segment_ID__c`.

This doesn't work:

```
select Id,Name,(select Id from Segments__r) from Account
```

because in the schema shown, the Segment object is the parent of Account. This is a parent-child subquery to obtain records that are children of Account, with the relationship name `Segments__r`.

I'd strongly recommend reading through the entire [Relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) section of the SOQL and SOSL Reference. It covers all of these variations of relationship queries thoroughly.

---

If your intent is that Segment should be a child of Account, your schema is built incorrectly: in that case, the relationship field should be on Segment, pointing to Account.

Comment: Thanks David Reed, I will have to go through the article on relationships.